# How make rails forms submit if using rails-api gem. Undefined method `protect_against_forgery?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have a rails application which is api only i am using gem rails-api. Now I am trying to create admin panel on it because we realised later that we do need an admin panel. But i think rails-api doesnt have good support for views.

When I try to submit forms it says `undefined method protect_against_forgery?` maybe because it doesnt supports  `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

I tried to define manually this method in my controller but no luck.

```
def protect_against_forgery?
  true
end
```

How can i submit the forms without getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

in your api controller put following line.

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

or try with

```
def protect_against_forgery?
  false
end
```

this  may be help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api#for-already-existing-apps), try to set `config.api_only = false` to `config/application.rb` file

Or, since `protect_from_forgery` is a method that belongs to `ActionController`, try to add `require "action_controller/railtie"` to `application.rb`